# Use of て form in a relative clause

Tags: grammar

> 彼女は風邪を引いて当然というような薄い服を着ていた

From what I understand, this can approximately be translated as:

> She was wearing clothes so thin that you could say: She will definitely catch a cold.

The thing I'm having trouble with is this part in the relative clause:

> 風邪を引いて当然

First, why is 当然 at the end here? Since I don't think it is modified by what comes before, is this order used to avoid 当然、風邪を引いて which may create a confusion with "She was of course wearing blabla..."? And secondly, why this て form? Is it just an unfinished sentence implying something else, or is it to avoid 風邪を引く当然 were 風邪を引く would act as a relative clause for 当然?

Comment: Could 当然 here be adverbial? "one would naturally say, she'll catch a cold".
Also while I don't have an explanation, ending stuff on て is kinda common in coloquial, even when it's not used for one of it's purposes, such as ordering someone.

Comment: Ending sentences on て usually implies something left unsaid as far as I know, even when it's for asking someone to do something. I'm pretty sure 当然 is not modifying いう if that's what you mean, since と "quotes" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be missing is that [~て当然だ](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86%E3%81%9C%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0-te-touzen-da/) is a grammatical construct on its own.

The main point of the sentence is this:

> 彼女は薄い服を着ていた 
>   The girl was wearing thin clothes.

The construct "風邪を引いて当然というような薄い服" further describes the clothes she is wearing: Clothes so thin as if to indicate it would be natural to catch a cold. (Translation is a bit rough around the edges, but it is hard to express adequately in English)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this specific construction with て+当然 although I understood the general meaning of the sentence. For now I think I'll just accept it as it is then.