# What does あって当然のもの mean?

Tags: expressions

> あって当然のものがたりない。

It's one of the meanings of 欠ける. Is "To lack a thing taken for granted" right?

I don't understand あって当然のもの grammatically, though. Is あって from 有る?

Comment: Maybe あって is connected to 当然の... I have no idea about Japanese parsing

Comment: @StarPeep I think your parsing is correct! (^^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practically, te-form + 当然(だ) is a pattern meaning *(The subject) deserves/should (verb)*, as mentioned in the following:

- [Why is て-form being used in 「そして罪を受けて当然な悪人が心臓麻痺で死んでいく裏で」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/101078/45489)
- [Use of て form in a relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62296/45489)

Here it is a relative clause, the subject is もの and あって is 有る/在る=*to exist*, as you think.

Thus あって当然のもの means *a thing that should exist*; and 欠ける means such a thing is missing.